# Python: reconstruct after pos_tag

Tags: python

I have to following results after using pos_tag:

```
list = [('a',` '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4')]
```

Now, I have to reconstruct like the following:

```
a b c d
```

I used:

```
[x[0] for x in list]
```

But, it resulted in

['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd']

Answer (score 3):

Use `join` method with `" "` it will make as string

```
data = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4')]
s= " ".join(x[0] for x in data)
print(s)
```

## OUT

```
a b c d
```

Comment: You don't need the `[]` in: `s= " ".join(x[0] for x in list)`  And you really shouldn't call it `list`.

Comment: No, the `[]` causes a list to be built, which is not needed.

Comment: @StephenRauch thanks for suggestion, edited the answer

Comment: Also suggest changing `list` to `data` or some such.  Bad practice to name things `list`.